# C++ Issues deducing template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have a template class, ComponentCache, that is essentially a wrapper around a `std::vector`, except that it only provides random access to the data.

```
template<class T>
class ComponentCache
{
public:
  ComponentCache()
  {
    m_Components.reserve(1024);
  }

  ~ComponentCache()
  { }

  //Get a component stored at some index.
  //If the index is greater than the size of the index,
  //resize it to the size of the index + 128
  T& GetComponent(const std::uint32_t& index)
  {
    if(index >= m_Components.size())
    {
      std::uint32_t newSize = index + 128;
      m_Components.resize(newSize);
    }

    return m_Components.at(index);
  }
private:
  std::vector<T> m_Components;
};
```

I have another template class, `ComponentStorage`, that is essentially a wrapper around an std::tuple>.

```
template<class... T>
class ComponentStorage
{
public:
  ComponentStorage()
  { }
  ~ComponentStorage()
  { }


  //Gets a component at some index from the tuple of components
  template<class Component>
  Component& GetComponent(const aecs::Entity& index)
  {
   return std::get<aecs::Component::ComponentCache<Component>>
     (m_ComponentLines).GetComponent(index);
  }

private:
  std::tuple<aecs::Component::ComponentCache<T>...> m_ComponentLines;
};
```

Finally, I have another template class, `World`, that acts as a place to keep a memory pool and the `ComponentStorage` class logically near eachother.

```
template<class... Components>
class World
{
  struct EntityMetadata
  {
    std::bitset<sizeof...(Components)> ComponentBitset;
    bool IsActive = false;
  };
public:
  World(std::size_t size = 128)
  {
    m_EntityMetadata.resize(size);
  }
  ~World()
  { }

  /*Entity Management*/
  const aecs::Entity& CreateEntity()
  {
    auto entity = m_EntityPool.Create();
    if(entity != 0xFFFFFFFF)
    {
      auto entityIndex = aecs::GetIndexFromEntity(entity);
      m_EntityMetadata.at(entityIndex).IsActive = true;
    }
    return std::move(entity);
  }
  void DestroyEntity(const aecs::Entity& entity)
  {
    if(entity == 0xFFFFFFFF)
    {
      return;
    }
    auto entityIndex = aecs::GetIndexFromEntity(entity);
    m_EntityMetadata.at(entityIndex).IsActive = false;
    m_EntityPool.Destroy(entity);
  }
  const std::vector<aecs::Entity>& GetActiveEntities()
  {
    return m_EntityPool.GetActiveEntities();
  }
  const bool IsEntityActive(const aecs::Entity& entity)
  {
    auto entityIndex = aecs::GetIndexFromEntity(entity);
    return m_EntityMetadata.at(entityIndex).IsActive;
  }

  /*Component Management*/
  template<class Component>
    Component& GetComponentFromEntity(const aecs::Entity &entity)
  {
    const std::uint32_t index = aecs::GetIndexFromEntity(entity);
    return m_ComponentStorage.GetComponent<Component>(index);
  }
  template<class Component>
    void AddComponentToEntity(const aecs::Entity& entity)
  {
    //TODO: Implement

    auto entityIndex = aecs::GetIndexFromEntity(entity);

    m_EntityMetadata.at(entityIndex).ComponentBitset.set(
      aecs::mpl::IndexOf<Component, std::tuple<Components...>>::value);
  }
  template<class Component>
    void RemoveComponentFromEntity(const aecs::Entity& entity)
  {
    //TODO: Implement
    auto componentIndex = aecs::mpl::IndexOf<Component,
      std::tuple<Components...>>::value;
    auto entityIndex = aecs::GetIndexFromEntity(entity);

    m_EntityMetadata.at(entityIndex).ComponentBitset.reset(componentIndex);

  }
  template<class Component>
    const bool EntityHasComponent(const aecs::Entity& entity)
  {
    auto componentIndex = aecs::mpl::IndexOf<Component,
      std::tuple<Components...>>::value;
    auto entityIndex = aecs::GetIndexFromEntity(entity);

    std::bitset<sizeof...(Components)> tempBitset;
    tempBitset.set(componentIndex);


    return (m_EntityMetadata.at(entityIndex).ComponentBitset & tempBitset) ==
                                                           tempBitset;
  }

private:
  aecs::EntityPool m_EntityPool;
  aecs::ComponentStorage<Components...> m_ComponentStorage;

  std::vector<EntityMetadata> m_EntityMetadata;
};
```

Throwing it all together, it should work something like this:

```
struct Position
{
  float x;
  float y;
};

struct Velocity
{
  float x;
  float y;
};

int main() {

  aecs::World<Position, Velocity> w;

  const auto e = w.CreateEntity();
  Velocity& v1 = w.GetComponentFromEntity<Velocity>(e);
  return 0;
}
```

However, I get the following compilation error regarding `GetComponentFromEntity`:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
     return m_ComponentStorage.GetComponent<Component>(index);
```

If I switch it up so that it should automatically deduce the type of `Component`, I instead get the following errors:

```
E:\CLion\AECS\aecs/World/World.h: In instantiation of 'Component& aecs::World<Components>::GetComponentFromEntity(const Entity&) [with Component = Velocity; Components = {Position, Velocity}; aecs::Entity = unsigned int]':
E:\CLion\AECS\main.cpp:26:54:   required from here
E:\CLion\AECS\aecs/World/World.h:69:49: error: no matching function for call to 'aecs::ComponentStorage<Position, Velocity>::GetComponent(const uint32_t&)'
     return m_ComponentStorage.GetComponent(index);
                                                 ^
In file included from E:\CLion\AECS\aecs/World/World.h:9:0,
                 from E:\CLion\AECS\main.cpp:2:
e:\clion\aecs\aecs\componentstorage\componentstorage.h:27:14: note: candidate: template<class Component> Component& aecs::ComponentStorage<T>::GetComponent(const Entity&) [with Component = Component; T = {Position, Velocity}]
   Component& GetComponent(const aecs::Entity& index)
              ^
e:\clion\aecs\aecs\componentstorage\componentstorage.h:27:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from E:\CLion\AECS\main.cpp:2:0:
E:\CLion\AECS\aecs/World/World.h:69:49: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'Component'
     return m_ComponentStorage.GetComponent(index);
```

It seems like the compiler should have no problem deducing the type of `Component` at compile-time, because `Component` is what's being returned. 
I feel like I am making some obvious mistake, but everything looks correct to me. Am I forgetting something important regarding templates?

Comment: You need a [mcve]

Comment: use template keyword before each method template invocation (of dependent type) inside template class: `m_ComponentStorage.template GetComponent<Component>(index);` to let compiler know that `<` doesn't mean less than but `template parameters list starts here`

Comment: @W.F. is it really getting confused by less than?  or is it that it doesn't know if it's a type or not during the first-phase of template name resolution?

Comment: @xaxxon template keyword doesn't say if it's a type or not this can be decided on context base/by using typename keyword. In other words - w yes compiler can get confused by `<` as if type of member is dependent at this point its member are unknown

Comment: That seemed to be the problem! I'll have to read some more into this. Was using the template keyword like this added in modern C++? I don't remember reading about it when I started learning about templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put yourself into the shoes of the compiler when it's parsing the line:

```
return m_ComponentStorage.GetComponent<Component>(index);
```

The type of `m_ComponentStorage` depends on `Components...`, which is unknown when parsing the code. How can you possibly tell what `GetComponent` is supposed to be?

It could be a template member function, but it could also be a simple member variable. For sanity's sake, compilers are instructed to assume they are dealing with a member variable in that scenario.

You can tell the compiler what it's dealing with using

```
    return m_ComponentStorage.template GetComponent<Component>(index);
```